# Unable to make noImplicitAny work in create-react-app project

Tags: typescript, eslint, create-react-app, tsconfig, typescript-eslint

I created a fresh react project using

```
npx create-react-app . --template typescript
```

It generated `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`.
I enriched them further to include `typescript-eslint` plugin, `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` and `eslint-config-google`.

The following are my resultant files:

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.52.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.52.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^40.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint",
      "jsdoc"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:jsdoc/recommended",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "google"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 2,
      "jsdoc/require-returns": 0,
      "jsdoc/check-tag-names": 0,
      "padded-blocks": 0
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I would expect after this that any implicit `any` inference by typescript compiler would raise an error however the following method in my `apiService.ts` file doesn't complains when type of `response.json()` is being inferred as `any`

```
try {
  const response =
      await fetch('some-url');
  if (response.ok) {
    const jsonResult = await response.json();    // This is being inferred as 'any'.
    return jsonResult?.categories;
  }
  throw Error('Fetching failed');
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  return [];
}
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: The return type of the `json()` method is explictly defined as `any`. The `inImplicitAny` rule does not apply here.

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks for the response. Is this documented somewhere?